# DocuSign API Client Pack Issue

Tags: php, docusignapi

So this will sound silly, I was trying to get started with docusigns API and the first thing I noticed was this.

```
// Download PHP client:  https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-PHP-Client
    require_once 'src/DocuSign_Client.php';
    require_once 'src/service/DocuSign_RequestSignatureService.php';
    require_once 'src/service/DocuSign_ViewsService.php';
```

I went to that link and Downloaded the Client pack, None of those files listed are in the client pack though. Are the requirments not updated? Have the names been changed?

I have downloaded the devcenter quickstarts and the Client Pack.

I dont even have a service folder in the Src folder, So not too sure what's supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kmiles1990123 we are in the process of updating the documentation to match the PHP SDK that is available on GitHub.

Meanwhile please refer to the link below for guidance on how to use the SDK.
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php

Hope that helps and apologies for the inconvenience.